# IIS 7.5 Detailed Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error occurred after enabling ServersideInclude with Windows 7 IIS 8 Express

Tags: iis, windows-7, localhost

I have ServerSideIncludeModule enabled using "Turn on/off Windows Features" Control Panel. On inetmgr's Handlers-Mapping suite, I have mapped it to handle my .html extension.

However after everything has been done and I tried to browse my Default.html (which has

```
    <!--#include virtual="includes/NavBand.html"-->
```

) it gave me the above 500.0 - Internal Server Error on this url

```
     http://localhost/myDir/Default.html
```

!!

If I removed my mapping, my default page works again of course without the include htmls.

I have checked the Permission, the users have read and script rights.

[image: SSINC-HTML]

However, the same implementations work fine on Windows Server 2008 IIS7.5 just not on my local workstation which has IIS installed on it.

Remarks: There is a file NavBand.html sitting inside the .\includes dir. So that is not the issue.

Comment: If you are using IIS Express then turning ServerSideInclude ON using Windows features may not work. You need to change IIS Express settings in configuration file. You can find config file at either one of following path.                                                                                           %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config    OR
%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: Hi Pankaj thankyou for your answer. What settings do you suggest to change in those applicationhost.config's?  I have changed a few things the errors just keep oscillating between status 404 and 500.0, interesting!