# IIS 8.0 Detailed 500.0 Internal Server Error - IsapiModule Not Found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, iis-express

I am working on a project that was originally built on a previous version on Visual Studio (pre-2013) and I am running into an error. I have searched and searched on google and stackoverflow including these resources:

- [IIS 7.5 Detailed Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error occurred after enabling ServersideInclude with Windows 7 IIS 8 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883296/iis-7-5-detailed-error-500-0-internal-server-error-occurred-after-enabling-ser)
- [HTTP Error 500.0 – Internal Server error when you open an IIS 7.0 Webpage](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942031)
- [The HTTP status code in IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891)

The second and third links are even from Microsoft's error article!

Anyways, I have checked out a repository and opened the project in my Visual Studio 2013 that runs IIS 8.0 express. When I try and navigate to a page that is hosted on the production instance, it loads just fine. When I load it from the local instance, I get a `HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error`.

Here is the request summary of the error:
[image]

And here is the error page itself:
[image]

As you can see, it throws a `500.0 - Internal Server Error` claiming that `The specified module could not be found.`  The module it is referring to is the `IsapiModule`. I have read that I need to ensure the location of the Isapi.dll, but I do not know how to go about this. I have ensured that the pages I've requested are in the correct project directory. This internal server error happens when I try and navigate to most of the site's links, both locally and on the production server.

I am running with .NET 4.0 framework.

Please let me know if additional information is required. I have tried to be as transparent as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Click Request Details in the first screen shot, and then check what is the module.

Comment: This provides the exact same information as the first 
[screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/H7Mn999.png)

Comment: Request Details shows much more things than the first screen shot, as it reveals all activities on the IIS processing pipeline for this request. However, you are supposed to analyze all such on your own, or with Microsoft support team via a support case at http://support.microsoft.com. Such tracing log can contain confidential information about your firm or home, and should not be published publicly in most cases.

Comment: Okay, I am fairly new to ASP so this should be interesting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to my errors were as follows:

- My project directory was listed on a network drive instead of the local C drive.
- The .asp handler was mapped to a 32-bit .dll (C:\Windows\Sys32\inetsrv\asp.dll) instead of the 64-bit .dll (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\asp.dll)

After moving the project and adjusting where the handler pointed, I am now able to continue threading through all the other bugs of my source code. :)

Sometimes its the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

I think one might have to do IIS tracing.
I have also have more serious problems with IIS 10.0. 500.0 Internal Server error. Module - AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule. For me, I have done reinstallation of IIS 10.0, updated my Windows 10 Pro and finally giving permissions to IIS_USERS. I also log in to Visual Studio 2015(Administrator mode) and attached to process w3wp.config file. Still finding difficult to go about tracing in IIS express. I had prior to that installed asp.net core runtime 3.1.7 and restarted iis several times. I am not sure about how to map the .Net handler to the (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv). I can't find w3wp.exe config file but found w3wp config(which I added to process in dll).

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
            http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
               EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= 
        (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet- 
          XXX.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-XXX-111;Integrated Security=True" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="XXX_DBEntities" 
    
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.XXXDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.XXXDBModel. 
           
          ssdl|res://*/Models.XXXDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
  connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-222\SQLEXPRESS;initial 
  catalog=XXX_DB;integrated security=True; 
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
```

I think Microsoft has an inbuilt problem of iis 10.0 express working with .NET Framework 4.5.2. I hope they solve this problem soon.