# IIS 8.0 Detailed 500.0 Internal Server Error - The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8, .net-4.7.2

I have a website that was running on 32 bit IIS 8.0. My website is built under  "ANY CPU" configuration. Recently we had an issue where the memory was getting overflown. We wanted to run the website as a 64bit process so more memory becomes available to it.

I turned "Enable 32 bit application" to FALSE in IIS. When running the website I get the following error:
[image]

Enabling 32 bit as TRUE resolves the issue. Is there anything I have to do other than setting the app pool to use 64 bit to make the application run as a 64 bit process?

I found something similar here: [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867186/iis-8-0-detailed-500-0-internal-server-error-isapimodule-not-found) but the Handler is different so I wanted to get some expert opinion on how to resolve this error.

Comment: FRT might give you more information on the error itself, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing However, if originally that app was deployed on IIS 8 as 32 bit a decade ago (64 bit was almost de facto option by then), I wonder if this web app is compatible with 64 bit at all. Find the original developers and only they know.

Comment: I don't quite understand your needs, enable 32 bit is the best choice, If you have applications (both 32-bit and 64-bit) that need to run in the same AppPool. It's no problem to run them on the same web server (in different AppPools), but it's impossible to run them in the same AppPool.

Comment: I used the same app pool I was running 32 bit version of it. I disabled the option for 32 bit and tried to run the ANY CPU version i built on the same app pool. DO you recommend i create a new app pool?

Comment: No, I just gave an example to illustrate the situation.